# A new kernel complied on base CentOS 8Fail to load/boot

Tags: centos8, kernel-panic

I have successfully complied the `v5.13` kernel and set this to default. Please see the logs below. However when I reboot the device, I. get the error:

> ../grub-core/loader/efi/limux.c:119:can't allocate initrd

Then Kernel Panic ad just sits there.
I do have new kernel in `/boot/` saved and intramfs for new kernel as you can find in log below. Any advice how to fix the issue.

```sh
[asingh47@snuc-desktop x86_64]$ ls -l
total 1139208
-rw-rw-r--. 1 asingh47 asingh47 994963240 Jun 21 10:11 kernel-5.13.0_rc6+-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 asingh47 asingh47 170145408 Jun 21 10:11 kernel-devel-5.13.0_rc6+-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 asingh47 asingh47 1434392 Jun 21 10:11 kernel-headers-5.13.0_rc6+-1.x86_64.rpm
[asingh47@snuc-desktop x86_64]$

asingh47@snuc-desktop etc]$ sudo grubby --info="/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-rc6+"
index=0
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-rc6+"
args="ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet $tuned_params"
root="/dev/mapper/cl-root"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-5.13.0-rc6+.img $tuned_initrd"
title="CentOS Linux (5.13.0-rc6+) 8"
id="a55c15ef2a3346cc8d76be9c2fb804c9-5.13.0-rc6+"
```

Comment: What if `can't allocate` is to be understood literally? Check the *size* of your old and new image sizes (`du -h /boot/*`)

Comment: @anx the /boot is only 10% utilized. I have configured 4GB for /boot.

Comment: I am not wondering whether the *initramfs* fits the *boot filesystem* (rpm would have complained while installing), I am wondering whether the *kernel+initramfs+whatever tuned does* fits available *RAM*. Your kernel package looks... huge.